# Ninject property or construction inject ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm using Ninject.MVC3.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<Repository>().To<Repository>();
}
```

Registering them like so in the App_Start.
It works just fine on controller that request this repository.
However I also have a few classes that need this repository.

```
        [Inject]
        public MemberShipService(Repository repository)
        {
            this.Repository = repository;
        }
```

^Example from a class constructor.
I've tried constructor injection this simply gives me errors because it requests an argument for the constructor.
Property injection simply doesn't work.

Do I need to do something extra to make constructor or property injection work in asp.net mvc3? I haven't done any other configuration inside NinjectWebCommon other then the line I posted above.

Comment: How are you retrieving an instance of this `MemberShipService` class? The `[Inject]` attribute is used on properties => it has no effect on constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to resolve an instance of the class using dependency resolver in order to use it, create an instance of your `MemberShipService` using:

```
var memberShipService = 
    DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(MemberShipService)) as MemberShipService;
```

That will bind your instance variable `Repository` using your constructor that you specified.

Comment: No problems, glad I could help